# Detect TraitCollection changes in ViewController with out traitCollectionDidChange

Tags: swift, uikit

When clicking on an edit button, the view controller navigates to a view controller that is a custom image editor. The editor does not have any `traitCollectionDidChange`. Also, it's in Objective-C. How can I change its toolbar to adjust to a change in dark/light mode? What I do currently is as below.

Before I go to the custom view controller I detect the current mode and adjust the custom controller's toolbar's icon color and text color by calling a function from inside `traitCollectionDidChange`. It works perfectly. But now I am on the custom view controller itself and here if I try to toggle the dark/light mode, now I am stuck as I am unable to detect the trait changes and adjust the toolbar's text and icon color, like white in dark and black in light mode.

So how can I tackle this problem, or is it even possible?

When I tap on edit button:

```
@IBAction func TappedOnEditBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let image = img.image
    else {
        print("Error on DemoImageEditor!")
        return
    }

    editor = DemoImageEditor(image: image)
    editor?.delegate = self

    editor?.theme.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    editor?.theme.toolbarColor = UIColor.white

    editor?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(editor!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    updateColorData(for: traitCollection)
}

private func updateColorData(for traitCollection: UITraitCollection) {
    let image = img.image
    let editor = DemoImageEditor(image: image)
    editor?.delegate = self
    if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        editor?.theme.toolIconColor = UIColor.white
        editor?.theme.toolbarTextColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        editor?.theme.toolIconColor = UIColor.black
        editor?.theme.toolbarTextColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `updateTheme` method you are creating a new (and unused) instance of `DemoImageEditor`. You need to access the one that is current in use.

```
private func updateTheme(for traitCollection: UITraitCollection) {
    // Simply access the `editor` property that set in TappedOnEditBtn
    if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        editor?.theme.toolIconColor = "white"
        editor?.theme.toolbarTextColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        editor?.theme.toolIconColor = "black"
        editor?.theme.toolbarTextColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

However, because the editor is shown fullscreen, your view controller won't get any calls to `traitCollectionDidChange` until the editor is dismissed. You can try presenting the editor with a different `modalPresentationStyle` so it doesn't completely cover the view controller.

Another option to try is to setting the toolbar text color to an adaptive color instead of black or white:

```
editor?.theme.toolbarTextColor = .labelColor
```

`UIColor.labelColor` is black in light mode and white in dark mode.

Not much of a solution for `toolIconColor` since it takes a `String` and not a `UIColor`.

Comment: thanks, I made the changes a you suggested, now the problem is sometimes in dark mode the , font and icon color remain black and some times in light mode , they remain , white

Comment: That's a whole new issue you need to look into. Do some debugging and step through the code to see what's being called when and with what values.

Comment: thanks, but this is the whole issue I am facing as I mentioned in question, the icons of the custom view controller do not respond as per the changes in dark/light theme, and they behave differently if I toggle the dark/light mode by being in this custom controller. simply put the toolbar icon and text do not change as per changes in dark/light mode

Comment: Just on a side note  the updateTheme method is called only once when I am on view controller , which is having traitCollectionDidChange, once I click edit and go to customviewcontroller , its never called when I change the theme from dark/ligh and that is why its not working as the method to properly update the toolbar text and icon is called just once

Comment: thanks, the .labelColor nor label does not work, also cannot dismiss this view, as I cannot detect the trait collection change when on this custom view controller